# TFS API Item.DownloadFile doesn't save the item into root path

Tags: c#

Using TFS 2010.

For example

```
VersionControlServer sourceControl; // actually instantiated...

Item item = sourceControl.GetItem("$/TeamProject/SomeOne.txt")

item.DownloadFile("D:\\SomeOne.txt")
```

The DownloadFile method is successful but the file SomeOne.txt is not placed in D:\, the root path. But saving the file into a sub-folder of D:\ works fine.

MSDN documentation says the following:

> localFileName
>
> Type: System.String
>
> Local path to use to save the downloaded file contents.

Comment: Your example isn't showing a download to `D:\`, did you mistype it?

Answer (score 0):

I have success downloading latest version of file to a different place that you actually workspace with this code..

```
VersionControlServer sourceControl; // actually instantiated...

sourceControl.DownloadFile("$/TeamProject/SomeOne.txt", 0, VersionSpec.Latest, "D:\\SomeOne.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run your app as an admin. In the later versions of Windows I know that you are not allowed to save files directly to the root of the C: drive (as well as other special folders, like C:\Windows, C:\Program Files, etc.) without being prompted for permissions, so perhaps the same security permissions apply to the root of secondary drives as well (I don't have a secondary drive to test this).